# satellite images - whole planet - on premise

Tags: data-request, geospatial, images

I've been tasked with creating a satellite map server for whole planet which is hosted on premise. It needs to be satellite images at a higher resolution than sentinel 2 (https://s2maps.eu/) - You must be able to see the road

I've done lots of research, there is a lot of info, and some of it way out dated and new things popping up all the time

my question is

1) Is there a provider of med-hi res satellite images for free (or low cost, under $5000)

this will be used for commercial use so needs to support this type of license.

The data does not have to be current, 2017 or newer is acceptable

Comment: have you seen these? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=satellite+image

Comment: earthexplorer.usgs.gov is my starting point

Comment: Thanks, would earthexplorer have high enough level zoom? the UI has very details pics but it says the provided maps are not for purchase or download

Comment: Do you have a specific area you are looking for ?